# How to do pattern matching in Rx. Where and Select in a single operator?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, system.reactive

Suppose I have this type:

```
type T = int option
```

and an observable of that type:

```
let o : IObservable<T> = // create the observable
```

I'm looking for a better way to express this:

```
o.Where(function | None -> false | Some t -> true)
 .Select(function | Some t -> t)
```

> An observable that only propagates the `Some` case.

There are several things that I don't like.

- I'm using 2 operators
- I'm pattern matching twice
- The second pattern matching isn't exhaustive (makes visual studio show a warning and feels odd)
- Too much code. The pattern repeats every time I need pattern matching.

Comment: You should be able to use `SelectMany`: `o.SelectMany(fun t -> t |> Option.toArray :> int seq)`

Comment: Sounds like [FSharp.Control.Reactive](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Control.Reactive) is missing a `choose` function. The project probably takes pull requests :)

Comment: Sounds good :) You may want to post a link to your PR here, so that future visitors can investigate its status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you use [Observable.choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340328.aspx) ? something like this :

```
let o1 : IObservable<int option> = // ...
let o2 = Observable.choose id o1
```

If you have a type that is not an option, say:

```
type TwoSubcases<'a,'b> = | Case1 of 'a | Case2 of 'b
```

and a partial active pattern:

```
let (|SecondCase|_|) = function
    | Case1 _ -> None
    | Case2 b -> Some b
```

then you can do:

```
let o1 : IObservable<TwoSubcases<int, float>> = // ...
let o2 : IObservable<float> = Observable.choose (|SecondCase|_|) o1
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. How did I miss it... And for other union types, you can use a partial active pattern instead of `id`.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @Lee I came up with a nice solution.

```
o.SelectMany(function | None -> Observable.Empty() | Some t -> Observable.Return t)
```

This works for any union type, not only Option.